# How to set the label background image scale to fit in Swift?

Tags: swift, uilabel, background-image

I have a label that is used for showing some message. I have created an image that I'd like to set it as my label background. Following is the way I have done it:

```
challengeCell.message.text = "    You have taken  \(historyArray[indexPath.row]) in this week"

challengeCell.message.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "challengeMessage")!)

    //this is a suggested attempt 
    challengeCell.message.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
```

I'd like to have the background image stretch and fill the whole label instead of getting duplicated. Any idea how can I accomplish that?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a pattern color for this. Use `UIImageView` to show the background image. Add a property to your custom cell class to hold a reference to the image view:

```
class ChallengeCell: UITableViewCell {
    let messageBackgroundView = UIImageView()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if messageBackgroundView.superview != message.superview {
            message.superview.insertSubview(messageBackgroundView, belowSubview: message)
            messageBackgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                messageBackgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: message.leadingAnchor),
                messageBackgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: message.trailingAnchor),
                messageBackgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: message.topAnchor),
                messageBackgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: message.bottomAnchor),
            ])
            messageBackgroundView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        }

        super.layoutSubviews()
    }

    ...
}
```

When you want to set the message background, set the image view's image:

```
challengeCell.messageBackgroundView.image = UIImage(named: "challengeMessage")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want that image should be stretched to fill the Label width. try this code.

```
challengeCell.message.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
```

Comment: please show me your code, i have tried it, works perfectly for me.